# unable to pass data on button click on edit form in laravel

Tags: html, laravel

`I want to pass the value to be edited on the form inside the modal, but it keeps showing the same value when I click another edit button

//below is my contoller, when I click edit button it shows  modal with a form with a value on it, but it cant changes the values as I click different edit buttons

```
 public function edit($merchant_id)
    {
        $merchants = Merchants_data::findorfail($merchant_id);
        return view('manage_merchants', ['merchant_details' => $merchants]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $merchant_id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'fees'=>'required',
        ]);
        $merchants = Merchants_data::findorfail($merchant_id);
        $merchants->fees = $request->input('fees');
        $merchants->update();
        return redirect('/manage_merchants')->with('success', 'Transaction Fee updated.'); 
    }
```

//bade template

```
     <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Merchant ID</th>
                    <th>Merchant Name</th>
                    <th>Transaction Fee</th>
                    <th>Service Provider</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($merchant_details as $item)
        
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $item->merchant_id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->merchant_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->fees }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->service_provider }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="edit/{{ $item->merchant_id }}'" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Update</a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>   
            </table>`
```

Comment: thank you, it is still not working